# JQuery Create UL from selected input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes. Whenever I check a checkbox, I want its label to be written to a container. When I uncheck the same checkbox, I want the label that was written to the container to be removed.  Here's what I have so far

```js
var topicSearchList = $('.filtered-keywords .topics ul');

$('.dropdown-filter-menu').find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

  var labelChecked = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text();

  if (this.checked) {
    $(topicSearchList).append('<li>' + labelChecked + '</li>');

  } else if (!this.checked) {
    $('.filtered-keywords ul li').val(labelChecked).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-filter-menu">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="one" />
    <label for="one">Topic One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="two" />
    <label for="two">Topic Two</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="three" />
    <label for="three">Topic Three</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- This is where I want the selected labels to populate -->
<div class="filtered-keywords">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/419/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-filter-menu').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
        var str = '';
        $('.dropdown-filter-menu input:checked').each(function () {
            str += $(this).next('label').text();
        });
        $('.filtered-keywords').text(str);
    });
});
```

**Update**: For adding into the ul.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-filter-menu').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
        $('.filtered-keywords ul').empty();
        $('.dropdown-filter-menu input:checked').each(function () {
            var li = $('<li></li>');
            li.text($(this).next('label').text());
            $('.filtered-keywords ul').append(li);
        });
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/420/

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can append it inside an <li>? whenever I do a append, the newly added text doesn't get removed.

Comment: Don't append. Just use .text() or .html()

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I added the html but it doesn't like adding new <li> tags. 
$('.filtered-keywords').html('<li>' + str + '</li>');

Comment: It worked perfectly! I tried to vote it up but it says I need 15 'reputation'. Pretty new to JS so I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You can mark it as an answer and later when you have enough reputation, you can upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, try: http://jsfiddle.net/kurund/bmszxjqm/6/

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        var topics = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            topics += '<li>' + $(this).next().html() + '</li>';
        });
        $(".filtered-keywords ul").html(topics);
    });
});
```